# Error executing stored procedure with FromSqlInterpolated in ASP.NET Core 6 with EF Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0, fromsqlraw

I have in my SQL Server this stored procedure with a single parameter and that returns a single record.

[image]

When I call it like this:

```
public async Task<EmpleadoDTO> GetEmpleado(string codigoSAP)
{
     var empleado = await _context.Empleados
                                  .FromSqlInterpolated($"GetEmpleadoByCodigoSAP {codigoSAP}")
                                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

     return EmpleadoToDTO(empleado);
}
```

I get this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

But if I execute the SQL directly:

```
var empleado = await _context.Empleados
                             .FromSqlInterpolated($"select empID as EmpleadoId,firstName as Nombre,middleName as Apellido1,lastName as Apellido2,Email as Email,U_CODEMPL as CodigoSAP,U_Activo as Activo,U_Sociedad as Sociedad from OHEM where U_CODEMPL={codigoSAP}")
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

it works fine.

Any ideas, please?

Thanks

Comment: According to your SP, it seems you have three parameter, but your sql command is just pass two parameter.

Please change the it like below and try again:

    $"GetActividadesByEmpleadoMesAño {usuario.internal_k}, {year}, {mes}

Comment: Hi In this case, when returning a list, everything works correctly, but if I execute an sp that returns a single element, I get this error System.InvalidOperationException: 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with EF Core 3.1 `FromSqlRaw` / `FromSqlInterpolated` methods when used with stored procedure cannot be composed so you should use `AsEnumerable` / `AsAsyncEnumerable`.

ref [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#fromsqlsproc)